How to solve the,"connection to port 443 timed out" error when retrieving MSYS2 packages?
I am trying to install MinGW-w64 via MSYS2 alongside VS code on a windows 10 computer. The installation finishes but when I use the <pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain> command to retrieve the packages it gives me errors, most of theM say failed to connect to port 443: Timeout was reached. I have tried to open port 443 using the steps here https://www.ssldragon.com/blog/https-port-443/ and temporarily disable the firewall but it has not worked. Below are some of the errors:
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-13.2.0-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-python-3.11.7-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 10014 ms: Timeout was reached
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-ada-13.2.0-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 10014 ms: Timeout was reached
warning: too many errors from mirror.msys2.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-objc-13.2.0-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 10014 ms: Timeout was reached
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-fortran-13.2.0-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 10014 ms: Timeout was reached
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-13.2.0-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : Failed to connect to repo.msys2.org port 443 after 10006 ms: Timeout was reached
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-python-3.11.7-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : Failed to connect to repo.msys2.org port 443 after 10006 ms: Timeout was reached
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-ada-13.2.0-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : Failed to connect to repo.msys2.org port 443 after 10005 ms: Timeout was reached

I tried opening port 443 using the steps here https://www.ssldragon.com/blog/https-port-443/ as I thought the problem might be that it is not open. I also tried disabling the firewall temporarily and running the installation file as administrator. None of these worked.

It could also be an upstream firewall (e.g. the company firewall if you are at work).

If you have access to a proxy you could try to set that using export https_proxy=

Okay, I will put it in an answer so you can accept this as the answer.

Yes I am behind the company firewall, do you perhaps know how I can configure the proxy on gitbash, because I am getting the same connection timed out error on port 22.

And as a result I am unable to pull or clone remote repositories from github.

Instead of using export https_proxy= before calling your command you can also put https_proxy= in front of one command to make only that use the proxy.

You're access to Internet seems to be blocked.
Maybe your organisation/company/school is blocking direct access.
If you have access to a proxy you could try to set that byt running the following before running pacman:
export https_proxy=<PROXYURL>

Or if you only want to use the proxy for pacman and not for other things run pacman like this:
https_proxy=<PROXYURL> pacman ...

